# Getting rid of complex numbers in a solution list

Tags: list-manipulation, complex

I have the following list:

```
[0.312712544956844,
 0.287641445144978 - 0.306854031390629*I,
 0.287641445144978 + 0.306854031390629*I]
```

I would like to get rid of the complex numbers (both Real & Imaginary parts of them).

I found a very similar answer to that kind of question

```
list={-1628.12 - 557.34 I, -1628.12 + 557.34 I, -920.324 - 1508.13 I, -920.324 + 1508.13 I, 2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7,2318.05 - 13.4031 I, 2318.05 + 13.4031 I}

Select[list, Im[#] == 0 &]
#(*{2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7}*)
```

When trying these codes I get an invalid syntax error. What would be the reason for that?

Thank you!

Comment: How about any of Cases[list, _Real] or Select[list, Head[#] =!= Complex &] or Select[list, # == Re[#] &] // Chop. Is this what you meant?

Comment: If you're generating complex floating-point numbers, would you consider this real or complex, `1. + 1.*10^-300 I`? I would expect round-off error in both the real and imaginary parts. If you know already that you do not have such edge cases as the example, then proceed with `Im[#] == 0` and so forth. If you're generating data and need code to handle whatever comes up, then I suggest you need to handle the edge cases in a deliberate way

Comment: What do you mean by "when trying these codes"? What **exactly** did you try?

Comment: I think @LearningLin's edit fixed the "invalid syntax error."

Comment: Or `list /. _Complex :> Nothing`

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simply and easy to use command: **DeleteCases**

You can set any condition to be removed from your list:

```
list={-1628.12 - 557.34 I, -1628.12 + 557.34 I, -920.324 - 1508.13 I, -920.324 + 1508.13 I, 2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7,2318.05 - 13.4031 I, 2318.05 + 13.4031 I}
```

Then using it the output would be:

```
DeleteCases[list, _Complex]

{2107.28,2145.53,2207.2,2289.7}
```

Answer (score 4):

`RealValuedNumberQ`, which came with V 13.3, is custom-tailored for this task:

```
list = {-1.1 + 5.3 I, 2.2, -3.4, I, 2 + I, 33, Pi};

Select[RealValuedNumberQ] @ list
```

{2.2, -3.4, 33}

`RealValuedNumericQ` also takes numerical constants like `Pi` and `E`:

```
Select[RealValuedNumericQ] @ list
```

{2.2, -3.4, 33, Pi}

Answer (score 3):

The OP hasn't returned to the site yet, so I'll give a few ways to test if a number is close enough to be considered real.  `Equal` tests floating-point numbers with relative tolerance (the same up to the last seven bits, usually).  So `x - y == 0` means `x` and `y` are exactly equal, whereas `x == y` means they agree to 46 bits or more (46 = 53-7), if they are machine precision; and `x + y == x` means `Abs[y]` is less than around `Abs[x] * 2^7 * $MachineEpsilon` if they are machine precision reals.  The standard C-like advice on comparing floats is not to use `==` but something like $|x-y| < t$, for some tolerance $t$ which may depend on $x$ and $y$. In Mathematica, `Equal` has such a tolerance built in, which one may find convenient, and its design allows it to be used for both exact equality and relative equality.

The tests take advantage of `Equal` except the last, which is a structural test and not a numeric one.  The additional numbers, shown below the divider, show the edge cases of each test.

```
realTests = {
   Abs[#] == Abs@Re[#] &,
   Re[#] + Im[#] == Re[#] &,
   Im[#] == 0 &,
   Head[#] === Real &}; (* effectively the same as MatchQ[#,_Real]& *)

mydata = {0.312712544956844,
  0.287641445144978 - 0.306854031390629*I,
  0.287641445144978 + 0.306854031390629*I,
  0.287641445144978 + 0.*I,
  0.287641445144978 + $MinMachineNumber*I,
  0.287641445144978 (1 + (2^7 - 1)*$MachineEpsilon/2*I),
  0.287641445144978 (1 + (2^7 - 0)*$MachineEpsilon/2*I),
  0.287641445144978 + ( 2^-24.301)*I,
  0.287641445144978 + ( 2^-24.300)*I};

Grid[
   Join[
     {Prepend[#, ""]},
     Join[Transpose@{mydata}, Through /@ # /@ mydata, 2]] /. 
    True -> Style[True, Darker@Magenta],
   Dividers -> {{False, True, {False}},
               {False, True, False, False, True, {False}}},
   Alignment -> {{Left, {Center}}, Automatic}
   ] &@realTests
```

[image]

These tests may be used in the several selectors of Mathematica:

```
With[{test = realTests[[2]]},
 Column@{
   Select[mydata, test],
   Pick[mydata, test /@ mydata],
   Cases[mydata, z_?test :> Re[z]]
   }]
```

[image]

Instead of `Re[z]` in `Cases` above, you can apply `Re` to the results to discard the imaginary parts of the selected numbers for any of the tests. Below I also include a particularly efficient method for large data using the vectorization of `Im` and `Sign`.

```
With[{test = realTests[[3]]},
 Column@{
   Re@ Select[mydata, test],
   Re@ Pick[mydata, test /@ mydata],
   Re@ Pick[mydata, Sign@Im@mydata, 0],
   Re@ Cases[mydata, z_?test]
   }]
```

[image]

Exact numbers like `7` and `3 - 2 I` behave differently, but consideration of them does not seem within the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Using `DeleteCases` and `Im`:

```
list = {-1.1 + 5.3 I, 2.2, -3.4, I, 2 + I, 33, Pi};

DeleteCases[list, x_ /; ! Im[x] == 0]

(*{2.2, -3.4, 33, π}*)
```

Or using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[list, Im[#] == 0 &], True]

(*{2.2, -3.4, 33, π}*)
```

Or using `GatherBy`:

```
Last@GatherBy[list, Im[#] == 0 &]

(*{2.2, -3.4, 33, π}*)
```

Or using `Cases` and `ReIm`:

```
Cases[ReIm /@ #, x : {_, 0} :> x[[1]]] &@list

(*{2.2, -3.4, 33, π}*)
```

Another possibility is a good idea proposed by @eldo, using `GroupBy` and `RealValuedNumberQ` as follows:

```
GroupBy[list, RealValuedNumberQ][True] (*Thanks, @eldo*)

(*{2.2, -3.4, 33, π}*)
```

Comment: +1 - I particularly like the `GroupBy`-solution.  `GroupBy[list, RealValuedNumberQ][True]` is also possible.